# How do we use Configmap utility in k8ssandra helm?

Tags: k8ssandra

I am trying to migrate cassandra DB to AKS using k8ssandra. I would like to retain the source DB's cassandra.yaml configuration in the target as well, like increase the timeout parameters ( to handle client requests). I see the configmap placeholder in the k8ssandra's values.yaml file. Would it help to retain the source configurations? Detailed guideline on how to use it is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

Support for specifying Casssandra configs via a ConfigMap was added in this [PR](https://github.com/k8ssandra/k8ssandra/pull/1180) and made available in K8ssandra 1.4.0.

The new chart property name is `cassandraYamlConfigMap`. Here is what the docs for the property say:

```yaml
# -- Specifies the name of a ConfigMap that contains a custom cassandra.yaml. The
# ConfigMap should have a key named cassandra.yaml. The values will be merged with the
# base configuration. The following properties should NOT be specified in the ConfigMap:
#    * cluster_name
#    * seed_provider
#    * authenticator
#    * authorizer
#    * commitlog_directory
#    * data_file_directories
#    * saved_caches_directory
#    * hints_directory
#    * endpoint_snitch
```

Here is an example ConfigMap:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: cassandra-config
data:
  cassandra.yaml: |-
    auto_snapshot: false
    memtable_flush_writers: 1
    commitlog_segment_size_in_mb: 2
    concurrent_compactors: 1
    compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec: 0
    sstable_preemptive_open_interval_in_mb: 0
    key_cache_size_in_mb: 0
    prepared_statements_cache_size_mb: 1
    slow_query_log_timeout_in_ms: 0
    counter_cache_size_in_mb: 0
    concurrent_reads: 2
    concurrent_writes: 2
    concurrent_counter_writes: 2
    read_request_timeout_in_ms: 90000
    range_request_timeout_in_ms: 90000
    write_request_timeout_in_ms: 90000
    truncate_request_timeout_in_ms: 90000
    request_timeout_in_ms: 90000
```

Here's how this works. The cassandra.yaml, jvm-server-options, etc. are generated as normal when `cassandraYamlConfigMap` is set. After the `server-config-init` init container generates the configs, then a new init container called `apply-custom-config` does a merge using yq of the cassandra.yaml in the ConfigMap and the cassandra.yaml generated by `server-config-init`. The ConfigMap takes precedence.

Make sure to pay attention to the properties that should *not* be specified. No validation checks are performed on the ConfigMap.

Note that you will need to use the `cassandraYamlConfigMap` property if you want to configure internode encryption. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70610253/configuring-internode-encryption-tls-in-k8ssandra) for a detailed explanation.

Lastly, I want to point out that there is improved support for configuring cassandra.yaml in K8ssandra Operator. The operator does not allow you to specify a custom ConfigMap but all cassandra.yaml properties are available in the K8ssandraCluster CRD. See [here](https://github.com/k8ssandra/k8ssandra-operator/blob/main/test/testdata/fixtures/single-dc/k8ssandra.yaml) for an example.