# How can I configure encryption TLS/SSL for Cassandra in K8ssandra?

Tags: kubernetes, cassandra, k8ssandra

i am new to kubernetes/helm.
I'm trying to configure encryption TLS/SSL for Cassandra in K8ssandra?
I've seen this example but can't get any further.
Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70610253/configuring-internode-encryption-tls-in-k8ssandra)!

I perform the following steps as described in this tutorial
Click [here](https://docs-v2.k8ssandra.io/install/local/single-cluster-helm/)!

```
helm repo add k8ssandra https://helm.k8ssandra.io/stable
helm repo update
```

```
cd ~/github
git clone https://github.com/k8ssandra/k8ssandra-operator.git
cd k8ssandra-operator
```

```
scripts/setup-kind-multicluster.sh --clusters 1 --kind-worker-nodes 4
```

```
helm repo add jetstack https://charts.jetstack.io
helm repo update
kubectl config use-context kind-k8ssandra-0
```

```
helm install cert-manager jetstack/cert-manager \
     --namespace cert-manager --create-namespace --set installCRDs=true
```

```
helm install k8ssandra-operator k8ssandra/k8ssandra-operator -n k8ssandra-operator --create-namespace
```

```
cat <<EOF | kubectl -n k8ssandra-operator apply -f -
    apiVersion: k8ssandra.io/v1alpha1
    kind: K8ssandraCluster
    metadata:
      name: demo
    spec:
      cassandra:
    serverVersion: "4.0.1"
    datacenters:
      - metadata:
          name: dc1
        size: 3
        storageConfig:
          cassandraDataVolumeClaimSpec:
            storageClassName: standard
            accessModes:
              - ReadWriteOnce
            resources:
              requests:
                storage: 5Gi
        config:
          jvmOptions:
            heapSize: 512M
        stargate:
          size: 1
          heapSize: 256M
EOF
```

```
CASS_USERNAME=$(kubectl get secret demo-superuser -n k8ssandra-operator -o=jsonpath='{.data.username}' | base64 --decode)
echo $CASS_USERNAME


CASS_PASSWORD=$(kubectl get secret demo-superuser -n k8ssandra-operator -o=jsonpath='{.data.password}' | base64 --decode)
echo $CASS_PASSWORD
```

```
kubectl exec -it demo-dc1-default-sts-0 -n k8ssandra-operator -c cassandra -- nodetool -u $CASS_USERNAME -pw $CASS_PASSWORD status
kubectl exec -it demo-dc1-default-sts-0 -n k8ssandra-operator -c cassandra -- cqlsh -u $CASS_USERNAME -p $CASS_PASSWORD -e "CREATE KEYSPACE test WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': 3};"

kubectl exec -it demo-dc1-default-sts-0 -n k8ssandra-operator -c cassandra -- cqlsh -u $CASS_USERNAME -p $CASS_PASSWORD -e "insert into test.users (email, name, state) values ('john@gamil.com', 'John Smith', 'NC');"
kubectl exec -it demo-dc1-default-sts-0 -n k8ssandra-operator -c cassandra -- cqlsh -u $CASS_USERNAME -p $CASS_PASSWORD -e "insert into test.users (email, name, state) values ('joe@gamil.com', 'Joe Jones', 'VA');"
kubectl exec -it demo-dc1-default-sts-0 -n k8ssandra-operator -c cassandra -- cqlsh -u $CASS_USERNAME -p $CASS_PASSWORD -e "insert into test.users (email, name, state) values ('sue@help.com', 'Sue Sas', 'CA');"
kubectl exec -it demo-dc1-default-sts-0 -n k8ssandra-operator -c cassandra -- cqlsh -u $CASS_USERNAME -p $CASS_PASSWORD -e "insert into test.users (email, name, state) values ('tom@yes.com', 'Tom and Jerry', 'NV');"
```

The files truststore.jks and keystore.jks are stored locally on the pc under the ./mnt/keystore/... and  ./mnt/truststore/... directory.
Here i create the secrets keystoreSecret and truststoreSecret.

```
kubectl create secret generic keystore --from-file=./mnt/keystore/keystore.jks -n k8ssandra-operator  
kubectl create secret generic truststore --from-file=./mnt/truststore/truststore.jks -n k8ssandra-operator
```

Now I have run the above examples.
This is the value.yaml

```
cassandra:
  version: 4.0.1
  cassandraYamlConfigMap: cassandra-config
  encryption:
    keystoreSecret: keystore
    keystoreMountPath: /mnt/keystore
    truststoreSecret: truststore
    truststoreMountPath: /mnt/truststore
  heap:
    size: 512M
  datacenters:
  - name: dc1
    size: 1
```

I'm trying to run this example as follows.

```
helm upgrade  k8ssandra-operator k8ssandra/k8ssandra-operator -n k8ssandra-operator  -f  value.yaml
```

Now I'm trying to run the configmap file.
config-file.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: cassandra-config
data:
  cassandra.yaml: |-
    server_encryption_options:
      internode_encryption: all
      keystore: /mnt/keystore/keystore.jks
      keystore_password: cassandra
      truststore: /mnt/truststore/truststore.jks
      truststore_password: cassandra
```

```
kubectl apply -f config-file.yaml -n k8ssandra-operator
```

i can switch to cassandra bash without any problems

```
kubectl exec -it demo-dc1-default-sts-0 -n k8ssandra-operator -- /bin/bash
```

In cassandra bash environment i can't find truststore and keystore files under /mnt/truststore/truststore.jks and /mnt/keystore/keystore.jks directories.

I'm trying to log into cassandra with ssl but I can't.

```
cassandra@demo-dc1-default-sts-0:/$ cqlsh --ssl -u demo-superuser -p JKv59QPynp3s0qGSf1DZ demo-dc1-stargate-service
Validation is enabled; SSL transport factory requires a valid certfile to be specified. Please provide path to the certfile in [ssl] section as 'certfile' option in /home/cassandra/.cassandra/cqlshrc (or use [certfiles] section) or set SSL_CERTFILE environment variable.
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked [this doc](https://docs-v2.k8ssandra.io/tasks/secure/encryption/)?
It applies to k8ssandra-operator (considered K8ssandra v2), while the links you found apply to K8ssandra v1 (where everything was helm charts).

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I tested it yesterday.

Comment: Could you share your K8ssandraCluster definition with the encryption settings in there as instructed in the link I provided?
In your initial post, you're mixing techniques from K8ssandra v1 (using a values file and helm upgrade) with some from v2 (using a K8ssandraCluster CRD) which cannot work.
You need to provide your encryption stores and passwords through a secret, and reference that secret in the K8ssandraCluster `.spec.cassandra.serverEncryptionStores` field, and turn on encryption in `.spec.cassandra.config.cassandraYaml.server_encryption_options`.